# Stripe custom interval_count per subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Is there a way to customize the billing interval count per a subscription or do I have to create a different stripe price for each subscription billing cycle.

For example:

I have created a Stripe subscription plan that's 20$ per month.

```
$stripe->prices->create([
  'amount' => 20 * 100,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
]);
```

Let's say a user wants to subscribe for 3 months, do I need to create a different plan that charges customer every 3 months?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you wanted a recurring Price that charges every 3 months, you'd create a new one with

```php
'recurring' => [
  'interval' => 'month',
  'interval_count' => 3,
],
```

Comment: Thank u, but that was not my question, I was asking if there's away to avoid create multiple plans for different interval count

Comment: Yes, you need a new Price for each different interval count.